# Precompiled templates with initializators (factory pattern) or single interface and method or what else?

Tags: templates, authentication, go, precompile, compiled-language

#### PROBLEM

I'm trying to use **authboss** (https://github.com/volatiletech/authboss) with quicktemplate (https://github.com/valyala/quicktemplate).

The authboss rendering system is defined by one interface: [Renderer](https://godoc.org/github.com/volatiletech/authboss/#Renderer).

I have created two different versions of the solution and would like to know which one is best **or if there is a third one better**.

1. https://github.com/frederikhors/authbossQuicktemplate_1, with factory pattern and initializators
2. https://github.com/frederikhors/authbossQuicktemplate_2, with interface and a `SetData(data authboss.HTMLData) (page PageImpl)` method

#### QUESTIONS

I don't know what to improve for performances.

- Is it possible to do the same thing differently and less in terms of hardware resources?
- Do you think I can improve using pointers somewhere?

#### RELEVANT CODE

1. Solution with Factory pattern and initializators:

   ```golang
   type HTML struct {
     templates map[string]func(authboss.HTMLData) templates.PageImpl
   }

   func (h *HTML) Load(names ...string) error {
     for _, n := range names {
       switch n {
       case "login":
         h.templates[n] = InitializeLoginPage
       case "recover":
         h.templates[n] = InitializeRecoverPage
       }
     }
     return nil
   }

   func (h *HTML) Render(ctx context.Context, page string, data authboss.HTMLData) (output []byte, contentType string, err error) {
     buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
     tpl, ok := h.templates[page]
     if !ok {
       return nil, "", errors.Errorf("template for page %s not found", page)
     }
     templates.WritePage(buf, tpl(data))
     return buf.Bytes(), "text/html", nil
   }

   func InitializeLoginPage(data authboss.HTMLData) templates.PageImpl {
     return &templates.LoginPage{Data: data}
   }

   func InitializeRecoverPage(data authboss.HTMLData) templates.PageImpl {
     return &templates.RecoverPage{Data: data}
   }
   ```
2. Solution with interface with a method

   ```golang
   type HTML struct {
     templates map[string]templates.AuthPageImpl
   }

   func (h *HTML) Load(names ...string) error {
     for _, n := range names {
       switch n {
       case "login":
         h.templates[n] = &templates.LoginPage{}
       case "recover":
         h.templates[n] = &templates.RecoverPage{}
       }
     }
     return nil
   }

   func (h *HTML) Render(ctx context.Context, page string, data authboss.HTMLData) (output []byte, contentType string, err error) {
     buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
     tpl, ok := h.templates[page]
     if !ok {
       return nil, "", errors.Errorf("template for page %s not found", page)
     }
     template := tpl.SetData(data)
     templates.WritePage(buf, template)
     return buf.Bytes(), "text/html", nil
   }

   type AuthPageImpl interface {
     SetData(data authboss.HTMLData) PageImpl
   }

   type LoginPage struct {
     Data authboss.HTMLData
   }

   type RecoverPage struct {
     Data authboss.HTMLData
   }

   func (p *LoginPage) SetData(data authboss.HTMLData) (page PageImpl) {
     p.Data = data
     return p
   }

   func (p *RecoverPage) SetData(data authboss.HTMLData) PageImpl {
     p.Data = data
     return p
   }
   ```

Comment: Is there a problem you need solved, or you're just looking for general code review?

Comment: Code review, better ways of doing things, ideas, pointers or not... Something like that. SO is for this kind of stuff too, or am I wrong?

Comment: On SO, we expect questions to be more about a specific problem. For more open-ended code review, try [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Opened, thanks: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225525/precompiled-templates-with-initializators-factory-pattern-or-single-interface But I hope you can answer this too please. Thanks.